# Second for-loop conditional statement not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a for loop where I suspect my second condition is preventing it from running but I do not know why. What corrections must I make for it to run? I am trying to get the index of the second number 87188.

```
var arr = new Array();
arr = [59998, 87188].

var arrOfIndex = new Arry ();

for (var i = 0; (i < arr.length) && (arr[i] != 59998); i++) {
  arrOfIndex.push(i);
};
```

When I output arrOfIndex I'm expecting arrOfIndex[0] = 1 but there is no value for arrOfIndex[0].

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo but instead of `var arrOfIndex = new Arry()` you can try `Array`.

Comment: What @norbitrial said: `Arry`...
Another typo: "." after `arr = ...` instead of ";".

Comment: `arr[i] != 59998` is false when i=0 = at the start of the loop = it's immediately skipped and never loops...
Test inside the loop: `if(arr[i] != 59998) arrOfIndex.push(i);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second statement in the for loop (arr [I] != 59998) causing the for loop to end the run.
So the running don't get into the for loop.
You can insert this value checking into a if statement inside the for loop.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you. I would have never thought to do that.